# Computer won't start when connecting SATA HDD

Tags: hard-drive, boot, bios, sata, post

I just bought a new HDD some time ago and recently I bought another SATA cable to have both HDDs connected at the same time, to transfer all the files from the older one to the newer.

When I connected both of them, the computer started working, I tapped F2 to go to bios to make sure it was detected, and then after 5-10 seconds the computer instantly shut down.

After this incident, my computer won't start at all when connecting the SATA power supply to the old HDD. If I connect only my new drive, it works without any problem. If I connect only my old drive, or both the old drive and the new one, and then push on the power button, the cpu fan simply rotates about 5 degrees and then stops.. and that's it, the computer doesn't start, and no sound from the PC speaker either.

Is there any way to recover my files from the old HDD and transfer them to my new one? I do not want to use the old HDD any more, I only need to save all my files.

Comment: Sounds like a HDD power issue/short, check your groundings and that the old HDD's not being shorted by something. Ideally mount it into the case chassis. If you still can't get anything from it then buy an external USB caddy/adaptor to test it with - but no promises that'll work if the drive is damaged/now faulty.

Comment: Did you make any changes or ever disconnect the power cable from the old drive before it started failing?

Comment: I haven't used the old drive for about 2-3 months, and it was disconnected entirely from the computer (both data and power supply cable), but the disk was inside the case chasis, and everytime i (dis)connected any hdd (with the sata/power supply cable), i turned off the power supply from the back of the computer (it has a button labeled 0/1).

Comment: Try with only the power cable connected to the old drive (leave sata disconnected) to isolate a power issue. Also try a different sata power connector if your psu has any extras.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds very similar to an experience I had recently, where a SATA port went bad and took out my HDD interface board in the process.

---

I recommend first that you stop attempting to boot the computer with the damaged drive in-place.  SATA is a hot-swappable technology and doesn't require the drive be connected at boot-time to be detected.   This is one of the reasons SATA is better than old IDE ribbon drives.   That said, you may need to go into the BIOS on your motherboard and enable hot-swapping on your SATA ports, as some come with this function disabled (my ASRock mobo came with it enabled, by my ASUS ROG board did not).

From there, connect a SATA cable you are certain is functional (as those can go bad as well) to the motherboard.  You can test the existing one by moving it to another drive and seeing if a similar problem occurs.
Boot the machine with only power plugged into the drive.  Once the machine is running and boots to the OS (to bypass Windows chkdisk risks or potential Linux kernel panics), plug the cable into the back of the drive.   The OS should detect the drive, one way or another.

To progress, you'll need to Google up some Free Data Recovery software.  DriveDrill will retrieve 500mb of data before you have to buy it, and it's very thorough and priced reasonably if you need more, so I used that.  This will scan the entire drive.   The danger is that the interface board may be dead, which causes the scan to read every sector on the drive as bad and unretrievable.   At this point, you are looking at either trying to solder on a new board from an identical drive or getting an identical drive and swapping the platters.  [Swapping hard drive platters](https://www.wikihow.com/Swap-Hard-Disk-Drive-Platters) is your last resort, and if it doesn't work or the drive has physical damage, you're done here.

In my case, I haven't swapped the platters yet because I lack the identical drive, but it's my next step.  Thankfully, my drive was just the one that was full of old console emulators and copies of CDs for games I now own on Steam anyway.  I hope your data wasn't anything irreplaceable, either.

Answer (score 1):

I am having same problem as above. Whenever i plug internal HDD to sata , PC won't start.  Then i was having a internal HDD externally connector via usb, so i tried it.  It worked fantastic.  I think problem with hdd current or power stabilization.  And in external case it is totally different. It handles HDD with an adopter.  Try it one. It worked for me..

Answer (score 0):

Please verify if the SATA cabe ordering is correct.

SATA cable on the motherboard starts from SATA 0,1,2,3.
Connect the primary hard disk with OS to SATA 0 and second hard disk to SATA 1 and so on.

Comment: Cable ordering has nothing to do with sata.

Comment: @The_aLiEn OS being on the first port does matter on some boards and in some cases.  Might be fixable in the BIOS though although not always.  Agree that cable ordering is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a dead hard drive. If you add a part to a computer and it stops working, then you remove the part and it works again, then it's pretty easy to deduce which part is giving you trouble. :)

Some things to try to make sure that the hard drive is completely dead and it's not some other issue:

1. Make sure you plugged in the appropriate cables to the hard drive. It sounds like you need 1 SATA cable and 1 SATA power cable.
2. As neomonks suggests, try switching the port you plug the SATA cable into on the motherboard.
3. Try a different SATA cable.
4. Try putting this hard drive into a different computer and see if you still get problems.

If you try all of those things and you can't get access to the hard drive, then it is dead as a doornail and you will need to send it to a professional hard drive data recovery place to access the data. These places can be expensive, so you might need to make a decision about how valuable this data is to you.